# Locking a section in multi threaded environment so only one thread will access it

Tags: c++, multithreading

To give a little more details I'm talking about Linux, gcc version 3.2.3 so not much c++11.

I want to lock a section in a multi threaded environment in a way that all the threads that will try to execute it during the time that 1 thread already does will just skip it (I don't want them to block on it) but just skip the whole section.

Only first thread each time will win and all others skip.

any suggestions ?

Comment: `std::mutex::try_lock()`?

Comment: Did you try anything already? Asking for _"Any ideas?"_ sounds too broad to be asked here. This may turn into an endless discussion which is what we don't want here. The site is rather about concise FAQ like question and answer pairs. You also may want to read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Given the lack of C++11, we'll need to know what environment you're targeting. One basic idea is to attempt to lock a mutex, and if it's already locked let that fail immediately. If it fails, you know some other thread is already executing the "only one thread" section, so you move on to something else. The exact route to doing that will depend on the threading primitives you have available though--pthreads or Win32, for example.

Comment: I'm looking for ideas for what to try, try_lock() was my first thought but I don't want to use it because than I'll have to manually unlock it and in case of exception I'll stuck with a locked mutex.

Comment: @zonzor18 You can write appropriate scope based lock guards easily yourself

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ are you suggesting to implement a combination of try_lock with lock_guard myself ?

Comment: @zonzor18 Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. The lock_guard could take a functor that is only executed when the lock is obtained.

Comment: @zonzor18: What you implement can probably be simplified quite a bit since you only have one specific set of requirements to meet, but yes, if you want exception safety with a C API like pthreads that requires manual unlocking, then nearly your only tenable choice is an RAII wrapper.

Comment: I think that try_lock is also C++11
thanks both of you, I thought that there is some kind of build in solution, guess will have to do it myself...

Comment: try_lock was new in C++11, but it's a (quite thin) wrapper around `pthread_try_lock`. The C++11 threading primitives are modeled closely enough on pthreads that if you have pthreads available, implementing the C++11 threading library is *fairly* trivial. Implementing C++11 threading on top of (for one obvious example) Win32 is quite a bit more work.